# How can I make my TestDataFactory class insert 30,000 records (9,999 records in 3 objects)?

Tags: apex, unit-test, governorlimits, limits, data

Title says it all. I'm making a standard TestDataFactoryClass. I want it to insert 30,000 records. For example: 9,999 records in 3 objects. I get an error: Too many SOQL queries at 10,000 records.

References:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_data?id=apex_testing

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_utility_classes.htm

Comment: You shouldn't be getting a query limit...but rather a DML Rows limit. Can you post the error message verbatim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done. Even if you don't have a single trigger, the limit of DML Rows is 10,000. That's for your entire transaction, not per statement. Since your entire test is a single transaction, you're limited to that many records and there's no way you can create more.

Note from [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm):

> Total number of records processed as a result of DML statements, Approval.process, or database.emptyRecycleBin: **10,000**

You can even verify in your test itself:

```
system.assertEquals(10000, Limits.getLimitDmlRows());
```

If you want to *act* on more than 10,000 records, you can do so using `SeeAllData=true`, though it should be used with care.